# How can make sure logically that my many to many relationships are created right?

Tags: mysql, database

I have basically 13 different tables. I have Customer table, a Sale table which is connected to Customer table because a customer can buy a Sell and that same Sale table is also connected to an Employee table because an Employee can Sell a Sale. Then I have an Order table connected to a Vendor table because a single order can be placed to a Vendor just as well as many different orders can be placed to many different vendors. But also the Employee table can be connected to a Shop table because an Employee can work at a single shop just as well as many employees work for different shops. The Employee and Shop table is connected by EmployeeShop which have reference or have foreign keys to both the Employee and Shop table. The rest of the relationships can be shown in the pic below. My problem is that I am not entirely sure that some of my tables that are connected to some of the other tables, for example, Ingredient table that is connected to the OrderLineItem, is entirely right. And also Order table and Vendor which are connected by the OrderVendor. Please any help or advice would be beneficial to actually moving on and forward my model to an physical database.

Here is the EER model

[[image: EER Model]

Comment: @ Strawberry not yet?

Comment: @ Strawberry  I just need some help making sure that relationships I mentioned in my problem description make sense to do. Do you think you can take a look at my EER model? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @Dhruv Saxena- Do you think you could help?

Comment: @Strawberry So you think I need to change the middle table to Order_Details instead of naming it OrderVendor?. That does make sense.

Comment: @Strawberry But if i do that how will I be able to still have a connection between the Order table and a Vendor table?

Comment: No. order_details would typically look like this: `(order_id*,ingredient_id*,qty)` [ * = component of PRIMARY KEY ]. The orders table would look like this : `order_id*, vendor_id, date` - so I guess you've just got it back to front (at least to my way of thinking)

Comment: @ Strawberry So I need to change the field names in the Order table and then just directly connect that table to the Vendor table?

Comment: @Strawberry Everything else is then fine? Just change the Orders table column fields to order_id*, vendor_id, date? Thanks

Comment: @Strawberry This is only way that I was taught to do it. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Strawberry I gonna update the model in a few minutes.

Comment: @Strawberry It's updated now for viewing. Sorry I don't know how to make it viewable on the outside just in a embedded link.

Comment: @ Strawberry do you think you can suggest an edit and change to the format to put the model pic on the outside?

Comment: @Strawberry I did exactly what you said to do.

Comment: @Strawberry the column fields don't have to word from word; something similar is still the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try that again:

```
ingredients(ingredient_id*,ingredient)
order_details (order_id*,ingredient_id*,qty) 
orders (order_id*, vendor_id, date)
vendors(vendor_id*,vendor details, etc.) 

[ * = (component of) PRIMARY KEY ].
```

Comment: Oh you wanted me to change all of the tables to plural and not singular and add the additional information. Okay, I will do that.

Comment: @Strawberry-So the purpose was to show me that I need to be more specific with my name of the tables and what goes inside those tables?

Comment: @Strawberry-I am confused about the OrderLineItem table about what's supposed to go in there?

Comment: @ Strawberry - I don't think I will need the OrderVendor table because if only one vendor is associated to a specific order and no other order can be related to that order, then it's a one to many relationship not a many to many relationship.

Comment: @ Strawberry, I made a lot of changes. I know it's not the changes you wanted to me make but I have to try to stay on track of the database design in best way I can. Can you take one last look and tell me what you think about? The one problem I am having is I don't know how I can connect my foreign key for the Order table in my OrderLineItem table.

Comment: Why wouldn't that table simply have an order_id column, so just like the table called order_details in the above example?

Comment: @Strawberry-How is this final version?